# Can I integrate 2 frameworks together? Vue and Cisco's next UI toolkit

Tags: vue.js, frameworks

I'm trying to make a web-application based on [Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/) and to have the [Cisco's NeXt UI Toolkit](https://github.com/NeXt-UI/next-tutorials) integrated in it. The reason for this is that I want the network map (and other features in the application) to be updated once new data is passed to the tool so I can create a real-time tool.
Right now I'm trying to create one Vue component and to render the network diagram (from Cisco's tool) inside, however it's giving me a lot of [errors](https://imgur.com/a/AY0oElA). I'll also add [some code and a structure overview](https://imgur.com/a/GcZgae0) of the application so far.
I have defined `topologyData` as a [global variable](https://imgur.com/a/OTEyfMK) in `data.js` (I think?).

Right now I have 2 questions to start with:

1. Is this possible or is there a better way of trying to accomplish my goals?
2. What would my next best steps be to solve this issue and to get the network map in a single component?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've solved the first 4 lines of errors by adding `this.` before the `topologyData` and `nx`. So I'm mainly curious about how to solve the rest of the errors (the ones created inside `next.js`).

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . Fwiw imgur is currently unavailable from my ip. The question is not constructive, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Yes, it's possible, I'm quite sure it doesn't differ from any other third-party lib integration in this regard. Consider addressing specific problems and providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for your reply and the tips, will improve in the future. Will do some research into third-party lib integration, thanks for giving me some direction! Will post back if I get stuck.